# Weird NullPointerException in Google Analytics Log

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I got this weird NullPointerException in an Analytics log from a user (Android 2.3.4)

`NullPointerException (@MessageProcessor$MenuMonitor:onOpened:-1) {main}`

I don't know what it can be related to, nothing in my code is named like that.
I recently added Millennial Media Ads to my app and I think it my be the culprit...

Has anyone ever seen this error? Any suggestions to fix/prevent it from occurring?

Thank you

Comment: This guy has the same error. I don't know if the suggested solution helps thought. http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=124868

Comment: Yah, I saw that. No use though...

Comment: I had the same, 2 week ago from one user (320x480, device not set). But I don't know what is the reason. What technology do you use in app? My app has ActionBar, makes SQLite queries, HTTP requests, has AdMob, Analitycs, Acra, some NDK methods. There is no Millennial Media Ads. Is it something similar to yours?

Comment: just for the record and perhaps to give some more pointers for getting closer to the cause of the problem - I also have this appearing in my analytics - for v 2.2.1 of PassAndroid: https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid

Comment: I just got this error again dammit. I've since removed Millennial Media Ads in favor of AdMob. I'm at a loss here...

Comment: @dimetil upon further inspection, my culprit fits your description. It is a 2.3.4 device 320x480 with no device info. Very weird...